# JNDI not able to find JMS ConnectionFactory

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms

My App is Running in `Jboss 7.1` and try to get `JMS ConnectionFactory` through JNDI Lookup  but gives error **javax.naming.NameNotFoundException**

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext();

// lookup the queue connection factory
ConnectionFactory connFactory = (ConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup("jms/RemoteConnectionFactory");
```

Comment: Have you tried to specify your context properties? context url, context factory to use and security credentials

Comment: My Jboss Using no User and my application is deployed in JBOSS and uses remote DataSource

Comment: Properties are not required if you are deploying your App in Jboss i read this in some posts